# Undo changes to entities using Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My C# web application uses Entity Framework 7 code-first. If at some point during the application workflow an exception is thrown, the error should get audited to the database. It should only persist the Audit entity. Any other changes made to the `DbContext` up to that point should be discarded.

So I need to undo the pending changes on the `DbContext` prior to adding and saving the Audit entity. What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried implementing the example in the following link:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-undo-the-changes-in-00aed3c4

However in Entity Framework 7 there is no Reload method on the `DbEntityEntry` class so the example won't even compile.

Note that the lifetime of the DbContext is managed by the IoC container and is per-HTTP request so disposing the DbContext isn't really a suitable option.

Comment: Why not use a new `DbContext` instance for your auditing? SOC (separation of concerns). In your IoC container you should be able to register your `AuditService` (I assume you have logic for your audit functionality wrapped in its own class/service) that it has an independent and owned `DbContext` instance injected into it.

Comment: @Igor Thank you for your comment. Sounds like a sensible approach. I just need to figure out how to configure the built-in IoC container that's included with ASP.NET 5/Core to inject a new instance of the DbContext only for my AuditService, and to inject the DbContext that is scoped to the HTTP request for all other services.

Comment: I figured out how to setup the IoC container, however have decided to move the auditing `DbSet` into a separate db context class rather than instantiating a new instance of the same db context.

Comment: Good deal, sounds like a good solution.